# Proposal: Add new Personal Review Queue for posts that have been edited after a up/downvote

Tags: feature-request, review, edits, voting, down-votes

One of the way to get out of a question/answer ban is to edit your posts to improve them which hopefully will see a reversal in the votes where either new votes will be upvotes or the downvotes will be removed.

The reality, in my view and experience is not so simple. When I downvote a question/answer I generally don't ever return to it as such even if the poster edits it and makes it better there is a low chance I'll be back to review if my down vote would still be relevant.

Now one can argue that an edit bumps a question to the top of the main page of a site however

- at a certain score (I believe it's -4) a question won't appear on the front page regardless if an question or answer that's been edited
- larger sites this "bump" may not matter as the question gets lost with other edit/community bumps and new questions
- some people (like me) may ignore a question bump because the modifying user's rep makes it assumed that edit would improve a post (ie. [modified 5 minutes ago](http://stackoverflow.com) [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) 925.5k) yet it's not recognizable that the post modified was the same one that was downvoted unless the modified link is licked on. in same cases the downvoted post may not have been touched and the editing user just touched up another question
- some people (also like me) may just plain well forget that there was a downvote cast somewhere (I certainly don't recall every vote I've cast)

---

My proposal is a new *Personal* Review Queue which is populated by questions/answers which are edited after an up/downvote has been cast **by the logged in user**, similar to the Review Queue which lists already closed questions that have since be edited.

This would be a new privilege I would couple with the [Vote Down Privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down). the link to this new Personal Review Queue would be located with the others as there already exists functionality to block access to Review Queues that one doesn't have the privilege to (on Stack Overflow I can access Triage, First Posts, Documentation: Proposed Changes and Late Answers but the rest are grey and not links. here on Meta the review link doesn't appear but if I [force myself to go to it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review) none of the links work) as such I don't see any problems with people accessing the /review page before they get the global review privileges

Posts that appear in this queue don't remain. when a vote is cast it's locked after so much time (I don't recall what) but it can be reversed when an edit has been made but the vote will be locked again, thus the post will only remain in this queue so long as the vote can be changed.

In regards to interface ideally how I imagine it would look similar to the Suggested Edit Queue yet rather than showing the difference between edits it shows the version of the post when the post of made and the most recent revision. if the data isn't available to tell which revision of a post a vote as cast then it can simply just show the post in it's current version.

the current version of the post will be similar to the First Posts Review Queue where one can interact with the post normally with the up/down votes, edit, Vote to Close/delete functionality. the top right buttons will also be the same with one difference

- **Skip**: skips the current post but doesn't remove it from the queue. when you reach the end of the queue it'll loop back to the start and go though anything that was skipped (to be honest this is what I expect Skip to do in any of the Queue but from my experience this isn't the case)

---

this proposal hopefully will give a greater chance to those in automated post bans to get out of the ban as their edits will be a bit more noticeable to those who had a hand in their ban and are possible the ones who can reverse the ban.

In the chance that this proposed Review Queue could be abused by users who gain more attention to their posts it is already established that editing for the sole purpose of bumping questions/answers (in the case of the active sort order for answer) is not acceptable, this review queue may also make it easier to spot this behavior quicker on larger sites

however the proposal can be altered to only list posts with down votes since a question/answer that's been up voted ideally wouldn't be put in a situation where the upvote would be removed or downvoted since an upvote should ideally be for high quality/useful/well researched content and edits should not be reducing the quality/usefulness/amount of research

Comment: So the review queue would be populated entirely with posts that only a few specific voters (or no one) could act on? That seems like a performance problem.

Comment: @NathanTuggy not sure what you mean by the *"(or no one)"* part. also what do you mean by it being a performance problem?

Comment: I meant that the server has to populate a bunch of review tasks that are probably going to be ignored.

Comment: @NathanTuggy that did cross my mind but i had hoped that the impact would be minimal. i would also hope that people clear the review queues when they see them rather than ignore them.....though with SO that might be more difficult but i wouldn't think this queue wouldn't get all that large

Comment: You underestimate the number of people on a site like Stackoverflow and Superuser.  I have seen dozens of people get questioned banned over the years at Superuser and none of them have been even willing to improve their questions to remove the question ban.

Comment: @Ramhound personally i don't think i'm underestimating the number of people on some of the SE sites but i may be possibly overestimating the number of people who would want to put in some effort to reverse a ban but get frustrated because they're efforts to improve aren't noticed and possibly overestimating the chance of a hidden gem coming from an initially bad question which gets fixed

Comment: @Ramhound If perf is a concern, make the feature opt-in. Then only people who have asserted they're willing to work these queues will have cycles spent on them. Also add to the feature-request: questions I've close-voted or any post I've delete-voted.